# NoMethodError: undefined method `instance' for Capistrano::Configuration:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano3

I have some problem with deploy.
rails 4.2.4
capistrano 3.4.0
I don't understand what's wrong. Can someone help me please?

```
$ bundle exec cap production deploy --trace
** Invoke production (first_time)
** Execute production
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
cap aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `instance' for Capistrano::Configuration:Class
/home/denis/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/capistrano.rb:12:in `'
config/deploy.rb:13:in `require'
config/deploy.rb:13:in `'
/home/denis/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/lib/capistrano/setup.rb:14:in `load'
/home/denis/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/lib/capistrano/setup.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in '
/home/denis/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/home/denis/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/home/denis/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/home/denis/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/home/denis/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/denis/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/denis/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/denis/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/denis/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/home/denis/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/denis/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/home/denis/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/denis/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/home/denis/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/denis/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/home/denis/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/denis/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/denis/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/lib/capistrano/application.rb:15:in `run'
/home/denis/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/bin/cap:3:in `'
/home/denis/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/cap:23:in `load'
/home/denis/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/cap:23:in `'
Tasks: TOP => production
```

**My Capfile**

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'

require 'capistrano/rbenv'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'

Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'capistrano
gem 'capistrano-bundler'
gem 'capistrano-rails'
gem 'capistrano-rbenv'
```

**My deploy.rb**

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
load 'deploy/assets'
set :repository,  "git@bitbucket.org:test/test.git"
```

Comment: How did you create this configuration? If you use `cap install` this usually doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

Your deploy.rb shouldn't have the require or load lines. Back up your configuration, delete your `Capfile`, `config/deploy.rb`, and `config/deploy/*`, then run `cap install`. Modify the generated config files to taste.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have Capfile directly under the project directory. If Capfile contains a line like `require 'bundler/capistrano'`

Remove it, it should just work.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your Capfile and not config/deploy.rb:

`require 'bundler/capistrano'`